# Html Helper to get values from Model State

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Asp.Net MVC 3

I seem to have a similar problem as this post answered by Darin Dimitrov. So, Darin if you are reading this, please help :)

[asp.net-mvc2 - Strongly typed helpers not using Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164235/asp-net-mvc2-strongly-typed-helpers-not-using-model)

The problem I have is I am looking for an html helper that will contain the posted value in the modelstate.

For example, if I use an editor for like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedTags)
```

I can see the value that was posted. The problem is I need a way to get this value without creating a textbox, I just want the string because I need it in some javascript.

I've tried DisplayFor, but that doesn't contain the posted value:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedTags)
```

By the way, I don't find this behavior intuitive AT ALL. I spent a few hours debugging ModelStateToTempDataAttribute from MVCContrib thinking it was a bug in their code to Import/Export Model State.

Thanks for any help!

### Edit - Added Repro Code

Take these steps to reproduce:

1. Start project. Property1 should be blank (required), Property2 should have "abc"
2. Change Property2 to "xxx"
3. Submit Form (notice ClientValidationEnabled is False)
4. Form is posted, redirect, load (PRG). Property2 textbox has"xxx" and right below you will see "abc" from DisplayFor.

Controller

```
[ModelStateToTempData] //From MVCContrib
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //simulate load from db
        var model = new FormModel() { MyProperty2 = "abc" }; 

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Success()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class FormModel
{
  [Required]
  public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

  public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.FormModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>FormModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty2)
    </div>

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyProperty2)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
```

ModelStateToTempData (MVCContrib):

```
public class ModelStateToTempDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public const string TempDataKey = "__MvcContrib_ValidationFailures__";

        /// <summary>
        /// When a RedirectToRouteResult is returned from an action, anything in the ViewData.ModelState dictionary will be copied into TempData.
        /// When a ViewResultBase is returned from an action, any ModelState entries that were previously copied to TempData will be copied back to the ModelState dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

            var controller = filterContext.Controller;

            if(filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)
            {
                //If there are failures in tempdata, copy them to the modelstate
                CopyTempDataToModelState(controller.ViewData.ModelState, controller.TempData);
                return;
            }

            //If we're redirecting and there are errors, put them in tempdata instead (so they can later be copied back to modelstate)
            if((filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult || filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) && !modelState.IsValid)
            {
                CopyModelStateToTempData(controller.ViewData.ModelState, controller.TempData);
            }
        }

        private void CopyTempDataToModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TempDataDictionary tempData)
        {
            if(!tempData.ContainsKey(TempDataKey)) return;

            var fromTempData = tempData[TempDataKey] as ModelStateDictionary;
            if(fromTempData == null) return;

            foreach(var pair in fromTempData)
            {
                if (modelState.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
                {
                    modelState[pair.Key].Value = pair.Value.Value;

                    foreach(var error in pair.Value.Errors)
                    {
                        modelState[pair.Key].Errors.Add(error);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    modelState.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CopyModelStateToTempData(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TempDataDictionary tempData)
        {
            tempData[TempDataKey] = modelState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DisplayFor` is the correct method. Check your `QueryString` to see if there is a value set to `SelectedTags` as those, I'm pretty sure` are displayed first over the actual model value.

Comment: @BuildStarted no query strings. I have a test page with both EditorFor and DisplayFor and only EditorFor displays the posted value.

Comment: Can you post your code please (view model, action method and a view)? DisplayFor should do the job.

Comment: @BuildStarted code added

Answer (score 4):

you can read these values from modelstate dictionary like

```
<%:Html.ViewData.ModelState["key"] %>
```

However, it seems to me that `SelectedTags` is an enumeration of objects that is displayed for editing when you call `EditorFor(model=>model.SelectedTags)`. in this scenario it is highly unlikely that you get anything by calling `Html.ViewData.ModelState["SelectedTags"]`. you will have to iterate over the keys in `ModelState` dictionary instead and check if key begins with `SelectedTags` prefix and then u can read its value accordinly.

Comment: It is not an enumeration, it is a string. Mmhh, is this the only way? It seems like there should be a built in helper that works like the editors/input

Comment: if u could post ur post action result and editor template we will be in better position to help

Comment: This is the closest I've found, but will leave question open for a bit in hopes someone will post a built in HtmlHelper (preferably strong typed) that has this logic.

Comment: Actually, now that I've tried it, yes I can get data out, but it will be null if model state is not set (seems obvious now). So it doesn't reproduce the same behavior as in input helpers since the input helpers check additional sources than modelstate

Comment: and that additional source is the model object passed to the View

Answer (score 1):

In your Views -> Shared -> DisplayTemplates, create `SelectedTags.cshtml`

This will be your display template. Inside write something on the lines of

```
@model YourProject.WebUI.Models.SelectedTags

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count(); i++){
   // Assuming that selected tags contains a list of tags.
   // Replace <p> with whatever feels suitable
   <p>Model.Tags[i]</p>
}
```

You can then use this display template in your views:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedTags,"SelectedTags")
```

This should also work:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedTags)
```