# ASP.NET MVC 5 rendering model with wrong data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Action in Controller:

```cs
    public JsonResult AccountEdit(Guid? id) //id = 4a01aadd-c61a-4524-95f6-e88a665c0745
    {
        //ModelState.Clear(); <------- strange code
        var model = DAL.AccountGet(id); <-- get model from database

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                html = this.RenderPartialView("View", model),
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

The rendered View:

```
<div>@Model.Id</div> d2afb9a8-fb43-4237-9f34-abc7e5b59a41
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</div> 4a01aadd-c61a-4524-95f6-e88a665c0745
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Id)</div> 4a01aadd-c61a-4524-95f6-e88a665c0745
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) 4a01aadd-c61a-4524-95f6-e88a665c0745
```

Only in line1 is the correct `ID`

a) If uncomment `ModelState.Clear()` in all lines will be "`d2afb9a8-fb43-4237-9f34-abc7e5b59a41`" - correct value.

b) if change AccountEdit(Guid? id) to AccountEdit(Guid? **id2**)

c) other property of model (missing in the parameters) rendered correct

My question is why?

[Sample solution](https://github.com/AlexandrM/asp.mvc.model.bug)

Comment: What is the logic within the class (get property Id)?

Comment: No any logic public Guid Id { get; set; } Model.Id in view is correct. Helpers ....For() work strange

Comment: Interesting, do you have a mini project where you isolated this behavior ? I could not replicate this

Comment: HTML helpers give precedence to values in the ModelState over values in the view model. If you want to prevent that, that's what `ModelState.Clear()`is for. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164235/asp-net-mvc2-strongly-typed-helpers-not-using-model

Comment: https://github.com/AlexandrM/asp.mvc.model.bug